# angularjs form $dirty lost when view is changed, but not datas

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs app I have a form and I need to know if `$dirty` is set to `true` or `false` for each input (for applied the good class - material design style). When I go on an other view - it's an other controller - and after returning to the original view, data is still here, but `$dirty` is set to `false`, even if it was to `true`. It is the *correct* behavior ? So i need a root controller for these two views ?

Comment: What browser is this in? I have a funny feeling this is Chrome or Firefox trying to be smart and remember your unsaved input values for you. As helpful as that might be, Angular is not aware that the browser has repopulated the values, so it doesn't think the input has anything in it. Hence why `$dirty` is false.